# How to display a pipe (|) in Spyder editor?

Tags: pipe, spyder

I cannot find how to display a pipe symbol with Spyder's editor.  It exists in the text but is displayed as /.  What's going on?  Screen shot attached to be clear about what I'm trying to describe.  This is on a Macbook, Spyder 5.4.3.

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem?  How, when, where, why ... are you using a pipe? What does 'how to display a pipe symbol' mean? In what way do you intend for the pipe to be displayed?

Comment: By "pipe symbol" I mean |. a vertical bar, on most keyboards it's shift-\.  inPython, ord(|) = 124.  As in this browser window, when I type shift-\. I expect to see a |, not a /.  In fact, when I am editing some Python code and press shf-\. I see / in Spyder, but when I view te same file in, say, Vim, I see a |.

Comment: As to "why": It's part of the specification of the problem: such symbols occur in the input stream and must be detected.  A simple " if ch == '|' " is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm calmed down now. The answer is that Spyder's font for quoted strings adds a bit of slant to all characters, including the pipe symbol.  Comparing the quoted pipe to the quoted slash, the pipe has less slant, like what a quoted I has.  I just have to train my eye to the difference.  viewed as an isolated character, '|' looks almost like a /, but not quite as much slant.  You may now return to your families.

Comment: Better yet, Preferences->Appearance->Syntax Highlighting Scheme/Edit selected scheme allows me to turn off italicization of strings.  Who knew? :)

Comment: That’s it! Was just about to post this rationale and fix for you; I see you’ve gotten there on your own. Glad you’ve gotten it sorted.  (Apologies for the delay; we’re apparently in very different time zones.)